# Wordpress force user to fill the form before view any site content

Tags: php, wordpress, splash-screen

I'm very new in wordpress. I'm in a big trouble. My client need a starting page(form) for a website before any page content loads. Only After the verification of this form , user will allow to view any content. Somebody please help me. I don't know how to start this. Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can offer more detail for us to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom page template that sets a cookie.  Then in header.php, check for the cookie and if it is not set, redirect to the custom page.  Be sure NOT to use header.php in the validation page.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I created a splash page like this "domain.com/welcome". And in header checking the cookie value and redirecting appropriately. It works but i don't need this "welcome" url So how can i do this with domain.com itself. Sorry my knowledge is very poor. Please help me.

Comment: In my splash page i need to implement age verification and email subscription.

Answer (score 0):

You can process the form data to a cookie field, i.e. when the require form was submitted, set a flag in cookie.

Then, in your 'init' hook, check the cookie flag to decide whether to show the starting page or the content.